# SFTP Chroot Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, chroot

I'm trying to give an SFTP only access to his home directory to a user.

This is the /etc/passwd line for the user:

```
bob:x:1003:1003::/home/bob:/bin/false
```

I edited the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file like that:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

Match user bob
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then I restart ssh: `sudo service ssh restart`

If I try `sftp bob@myserver.com` everything works well.

Then I try to Chroot bob to his home, so I add `ChrootDirectory /home/bob` in the right place:

```
Match user bob
            ChrootDirectory /home/bob
            AllowTcpForwarding no
            X11Forwarding no
            ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I changed the permission to bob home:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root      4096 2014-02-27 13:13 bob
```

Now when I try sftp bob@myserver.com the answer is:

```
Write failed: Broken pipe
Connection closed
```

my OpenSSH version is 1:5.5p1-4ubuntu6

Where I'm wrong??? Where I can look to solve my problem???

EDIT:
after a bit of debugging i found this error message:

```
bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
```

Comment: make sure that the chroot directory is owned by root.

Comment: Ok resolved... error messages doesn't lie...

The / directory was not owned by root but by another admin user (incredible...), so after `chown root.root /` everything works.

THX to all!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to specify `ChrootDirectory /home` it will substitute to /home/bob automagically. Otherwise it is looking into `/home/bob/bob`

Edit:
Also make sure that the chroot directory is owned by root and is not group writable. If you need to have a writable directory then you need to create a subfolder

```
chown root /home/bob
chmod go-w /home/bob
mkdir /home/bob/writeable
chown bob:sftponly /home/bob/writeable
chmod ug+rwX /home/bob/writeable
```

Comment: Thx @Chris for the answer, but nothing changes...

Comment: probably you need to dig into some logfiles to see more details. /var/log/auth.log or similar

Answer (score 0):

man sshd_config

```
Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.
```

This works, because /home is owned by root and not writable by others users

```
Match user pippo
        ChrootDirectory /home
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

In this ways, that doesn't works, because ChrootDirectory /home/pippo is not owned by root and is writable by others users

```
Match user pippo
        ChrootDirectory /home/pippo
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```